# Accidentally deleted local file with TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn

Had a tree conflict on a folder that was moved, but that I had added an extra file to.

I, in a fit of dumbness, clicked "delete local" without paying attention.

Is it possible to get the file back?  Why doesn't things deleted this way by tortoise svn go to the recycling bin?

edit: file recovery tools can find the folder and the file that was moved, however it doesn't seem to find the file I added (and was deleted by tortoise svn)?

Comment: If it has ever been commited, you can just update (maybe to an older revision) to get it back; otherwise I am afraid it is gone... unless you have some clever hard disk tools that can restore it.

Answer (score 1):

If you added the file and the file was not versioned before, no.

The "Delete Unversioned Files" avoids losing unversioned files, moving them to the Recycle Bin: [Chapter 4. Daily Use Guide from TortoiseSVN Manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html)